# Spring authorization server in docker container get http 401 response code with sample

Tags: docker, oauth-2.0, jwt, microservices, spring-authorization-server

I am trying to build a microservice with spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server 1.0.2 and spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server in spring boot 3.0.4.
And I have included a custom authorization grant type.
When I test the application locally, it is in the happy path, but when I dockerize the application. It returns 401 HTTP response code.

To Reproduce

In my application-dokcer.yaml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://auth:8092
 
For docker-compose.yaml
version: '3'

services:
  eureka-server:
    image: xxxxxxx
    container_name: eureka-server
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring

  apigw:
    image: xxxxxxx
    container_name: apigw
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
  auth:
    image: xxxxxxx
    container_name: auth
    ports:
      - "8092:8092"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - eureka-server
  news: <========= this is the resource server
    image:xxxxxxx
    container_name: news
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - eureka-server
      - auth

networks:
  spring:
    driver: bridge
```

SecurityConfig in my news service (resource server)

```
    @configuration
    //@order(1)
    public class SecurityConfig {
    @value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuerUri;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/news/pre-authentication").anonymous()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuerUri);
            }
    }
```

When i test the Api it return

[image]

Expected behavior
Request is authorized

Sample
Code for auth server
https://github.com/Jethro-Tsoi/Auth-server

Comment: The issue seems to be with the resource server (api), however you have not provided any information about that. Can you enable trace with `logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace` (you can do this in the yaml file) on the resource server and post the logs? It would be helpful to enable trace on the authz server and post the logs for that as well. To do this, you will need to run the docker container(s) without `-d` (detached) so you can see console output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this block to the `AuthorizationServerConfig` in Authorization Server:

```java
@Bean
public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
    return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
            .issuer("http://auth:8092")
            .build();
    }
```